# I want to Remove "through Cashback" text in Terawallet - for WooCommerce Plugin In WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook-woocommerce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8zJF.jpg)

I want to Remove "through Cashback" text in every place of my website . I am using to get this cashback text from Terawallet-Woocommerce plugin . Can everyone suggest me a suitable solutions for my problem .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function woo_wallet_strings($translation, $text, $domain) {

        $search_string = 'through cashback';
        if (strpos($translation, $search_string) !== false) {

            $translation = str_replace($search_string, '', $translation);
        }
        return $translation;
    }

    add_filter('gettext_woo-wallet', 'woo_wallet_strings', 20, 3);
```

Use `gettext_{$domain}` hook for this. See the doc [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/)